# Grails - Date binding in Controller

Tags: data-binding, grails

I'm trying to bind Date params in my controller. I read somewhere that it should be sufficient if I have the date in format  `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`. But this doesn't work. The other option that I read was to add `_day`, `_month`, `_year`, etc. suffixes to the attributes that I want to parse, but this method doesn't work either.

So it's basically a one-to-many relationship, when on the many side is the date (an Action has a  `VisitList<Visit>` and the Visit has date).

```
// domain classes
class Action {
   List<Visit> visitList
   static hasMany = [visitList: Visit]
}

class Visit {
   Action action 
   static belongsTo = [action: Action]

   Date date
   String description
}
```

I parse all the params to the action instance like this:

```
// in controller
def save(){
   Action actionInstance = new Action()
   action.properties = params
   action.save()
}
```

The date is sent from view and has this format:

```
visitList[0].date=2012-05-15 00:00:00.0000
```

But the date is still null. The visit also has a description attribute and it works well. The param for this attribute is:

```
visitList[0].description=description
```

Thanks for any suggestions or advices.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try saving the Visit first and then save the Action? If that doesn't work you may have to convert the date from string to Date, Date.parse() method is depreciated in grails 2.0, try this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(dateString)
def action = new Action()
def visit = new Visit(date: date, description: description?:"", action: action)
visit.save()
action.visitList.add(visit)
action.save()
```

-HTH

Comment: Thanks. I want to save it both at once and to parse all the attributes with only action.params = params or sth like this.

Comment: The `Date.parse()` that is deprecated is the Java method that takes a single String parameter.  The groovy method [`Date.parse()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that takes two parameters is definitely not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code it's difficult to tell. You may want to try a [Command Object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects). Where is your input coming from? A View? If so, one typically uses the  and  tags to control the input. If you're not using those, you may have to manually parse the date using [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) {hint, use the `parse()` method}.